# Update using stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a demo test using a stored procedure to update data from user.

Here's my stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROC sp_CapNhat
    @maNV nvarchar(10),
    @hoNV nvarchar(50),
    @tenNV nvarchar(100),
    @gioiTinh bit,
    @diaChi nvarchar(150),
   @tienLuong int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE NhanVien 
    SET Ho = @hoNV,
        Ten = @tenNV,
        GioiTinh = @gioiTinh,
        DiaChi = @diaChi,
        TienLuong = @tienLuong
    WHERE MaNV = @maNV

    SELECT * FROM NhanVien
END
```

And class connect to SQL Server:

```
public static void LoadDataSet(ref DataSet ds, string procName, params     object[] parameters)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(procName, con);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(da.SelectCommand);

    if (da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Count - 1 != parameters.Length)
    {
        return;
    }

    int i = 0;

    foreach (SqlParameter pr in da.SelectCommand.Parameters)
    {
        if (pr.Direction == ParameterDirection.Input || pr.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput)
        {
            pr.Value = parameters[i];
        }
    }

    da.Fill(ds);

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

When I pass parameter from user to update I get some error casting variable:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a string to a boolean

@tienLuong int similar

Here's my code passing parameter to procedure in ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult CapNhat(NhanVien obj)
{
    return View("Index", Common.LoadDataTable("sp_CapNhat", obj.maNV, obj.hoNV, obj.tenNV, obj.gioiTinh, obj.diaChi, obj.tienLuong));
}
```

Can anybody help me fix this? Please explain...

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Is `obj.gioiTinh` boolean type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static void LoadDataSet(ref DataSet ds, string name, params object[] parameters)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(name, con);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(da.SelectCommand);
        if (da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Count - 1 != parameters.Length)
        {
            return;
        }
        int i = 0;
        foreach (SqlParameter pr in da.SelectCommand.Parameters)
        {
            if (pr.Direction == ParameterDirection.Input || pr.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput)
            {
                pr.Value = parameters[i];
                i++;
            }

        }
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Added i++ in above code.**

And function calling from your Action

```
 var dataset = new DataSet();
        var args = new object[] { "Hello", "World", 123, true, "ddd", 1 };
        CommonHelper.LoadDataSet(ref dataset, "sp_CapNhat", args);
```